# Identification of particle and antiparticle in lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Lagrangians that include a particle field and its corresponding antiparticle field always have the particle field and the antiparticle field in the same terms.

For example, in the theory of a complex scalar boson $\phi$, the Lagrangian is a function of $\phi^{*}\phi$, and not of $\phi$ and $\phi^{*}$ separately.

Also, in the theory of a Dirac fermion $\psi$, the the Lagrangian is a function of $\bar{\psi}\psi$, and not of $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ separately.

This makes it difficult to see if the fermion is $\psi$ and the antifermion is $\bar{\psi}$ or if, the fermion is $\bar{\psi}$ and the antifermion is $\psi$.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the fermion" and "the antifermion"? They're both fermions, and they're antiparticles of each other. It doesn't make sense to say one or the other is the "antifermion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to separate particles from antiparticle because of the following principle: the process of absorption of a particle and the process of emission of an antiparticle is indistinguishable.

The field operator $\psi$ is an operator that create a particle or absorb an antiparticle, i. e. is a linear combination of $a$ and $a_c^{\dagger}$, where $c$ means conjugated particle.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered briefly, but you may would like to look Ch. 5 of Weinberg's course Vol. 1 for a more thorough discussion of this topic. Namely, the inevitable appearance of antiparticles in QFT as a consequence of Lorentz symmetry.